# How can I store a one to many, where many only has one attribute in CoreData (simplified)?

Tags: xcode, core-data, one-to-many

I have an entity schedule. 
This schedule has some attributes like name, startdate, enddate, etc.
It also has a one to many relationship to times.
Times is an entity with only one attribute 'time' of the NSDate type.

So each schedule can have one or more times.

My previous implementation was an NSArray that I transformed into NSData for storage inside the schedule entity. I didn't like that.

Now schedule.times gives an NSSet with Time entities.
So when I want a for loop I need to do:

```
for(Time *time in schedule.times) {
    NSLog("%@", time.time);
}
```

My question: is there no way I can set it up so that I can just do the following?

```
for(Time *time in schedule.times) {
    NSLog("%@", time);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for the specific simple case you've asked about, you can simply implement a `-description` method on the `Time` class to return `self.time.description`.

When you format an object into a string using the `%@` format specifier, it simply asks the object for its description and prints the resulting string.

However, I suspect that your simple case is misleading because you don't really care about logging the object.  What do you really care about?

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm not interested in just logging it. I guess there is simpler way to do this. I was looking for a way where schedule.times returns an NSSet of NSDates instead of an NSSet of Time's which contains an NSDate.

Comment: You might use `[schedule valueForKeyPath:@"times.time"]`. Applying `-valueForKey:` to an `NSSet` synthesizes a set of all of the values obtained by applying `-valueForKey:` to the members of the set.

Comment: @ken, put that in your answer and I'll delete mine - cross posted there!